# Angular hide div on scroll down, show div on show up

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular11

I have make some research, just saw on window scroll event. How can I make it on div scroll event? I have tried many method, still can't make it.

If the div(content) scroll down hide header, if the div(content) scroll up show header.

**HTML**

```
<header *ngIf="scroll">
    <app-toolbar (OpenDrawer)="OpenDrawer()"></app-toolbar>
    </header>
<div class="app-body">
    <content  scrollEvents="true" scrolling>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </content>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
import ...
...
enum VisibilityState {
  Visible = 'visible',
  Hidden = 'hidden'
}

enum Direction {
  Up = 'Up',
  Down = 'Down'
}

@Component
...
export class TabLayout implements OnInit {
...
    @Input() stickyHeader = false;
    scroll() {
        const scroll$ = fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'scroll').pipe(
          throttleTime(10),
          map(() => this.el.nativeElement.pageYOffset),
          pairwise(),
          map(([y1, y2]): Direction => (y2 < y1 ? Direction.Up : Direction.Down)),
          distinctUntilChanged(),
          share()
        );

        const scrollUp$ = scroll$.pipe(
          filter(direction => direction === Direction.Up)
        );

        const scrollDown = scroll$.pipe(
          filter(direction => direction === Direction.Down)
        );

        scrollUp$.subscribe(() => (this.isVisible = true));
        scrollDown.subscribe(() => (this.isVisible = false));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this the same way you would do it in a normal website, you only need the reference to the DOM element, and you can do that using @ViewChild:

HTML:

```
<div #scroller></div>

<div *ngIf="displayDiv"></div>    // Element you want to hide on scroll
```

TS (Javascript)

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('scroller')
  scroller: ElementRef;

  displayDiv = true;

  ngOnInit() {
  
     this.scroller.nativeElement.onscroll = () => {

         let top = this.scroller.nativeElement.scrollTop;

         if (top > 0) {               // We scrolled down
             this.displayDiv = false;
         }
         else {
             this.displayDiv = true;
         }

     }

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, is scroll up show, scroll down hide not scroll to top show.